# SharePoint Online Unable To Modify Default New Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, custom-form, validation

I have created a custom list in SharePoint Online and would like to modify the new form by including some javascript for conditional validation via JSLink.

When I go to `List > Form Web Parts > Default New Form` the form loads but there is no ribbon to be able to modify anything. Is there an option I need to enable to so I can modify the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you are on this form, you need to use settings icon on top right corner.
there you will get edit page option.
use this option to add new script editor webpart and add custom javascript.